# Strunk & White / Copy editor badges

Tags: support, edit-badges

I have found these queries

- [Check Strunk und White process, for current user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white)
- [How Many Edits Have I Made?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made?UserId=431537)

Does this queries work?

Standing on what the queries returns I have only done 6 edits. But these are far less than the real edits I have done in the last two days...

Is there a way to verify the real number of post edited by a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SE Data Explorer is based on [the monthly data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/), so it's not going to be up to date with what you've done in the past two days.

Comment: so you mean it includes the total edits until november 30?

Comment: @Lorenzo It's actually only through October 31 at the moment; you can tell from the "most recent" date on the right-side of the [homepage](http://odata.stackexchange.com/). The November data dump [isn't out yet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/); it probably will be soon

Comment: They won't be accurate anyway - the queries only count edits that haven't been later revised by someone else ("LastEditorUserId").

Comment: Now that the dump contains post history, we *can* find out more accurately (exactly?), though the queries need to be updated.